# How do web cookies work in Outlook for Android and Outlook for iOS

Tags: android, ios, cookies, outlook

My issue is as follows:

in an email we add a tracker that calls my rails based application, it checks to see if a cookie is present, if not it generates a uuid and sets that cookie to it with a 5 year expiry.

If I leave and open the email, and at least some times, the cookie is not found and in return, my rails application sets another cookie.

This issue seems to only be on the outlook app for ios and android as far as I can tell.

Does anyone have experience with cookies being cached/saved on these apps? any solutions to uniquely identifying a user without using a cookie or IP address or url?

essentially the same url is being sent to everyone due to constraints of the email world and we would like to identify a user uniquely to the best of our ability